# SQL Server Migration- SSRS Reports don't match old server

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2016

I am looking for some direction on how to solve this SSRS problem.  Basically, I am migrating a 2012 sql server to a 2016 server.  I am on the last leg which was to ensure the SSRS reports being sent out match the old prod reports.

Two of the three reports being sent out are inaccurate.  One report shows up completely missing all numerical data, aside from the layout of the report.  The second report has all the data in the correct locations, however it is doubling the data in one of its 3 columns. They are connected to an internal data source.

I transferred these reports by downloading (rdl) them from the Old Prod SSRS and simply uploading them to the new Prod SSRS. I have tried tinkering with the report builder/visual studio but I'm not sure what to look for.

Can you please point me in the right direction of where to look or if there is an easier way to migrate said reports?

Comment: Your process of downloading from the old server and then re-uploading the reports to the new server has worked for me before. You can sometimes get problems with formatting and design of reports such as you are having. The only way I've got around this before is to recreate the report from scratch in the new server. Its not as hard a process as you may think as all the design work is done for you, you just have to manually copy information from one report to another

Comment: Check your dataset/datasource are pointing to the correct locations. On the SSRS web portal, check the share datasets (if any) and datasources are correct. By default there are not overwritten when reports are deployed.